# Primeng datatable cell background color change

Tags: primeng

Need to change `<td>` background color if user change the value from dropdown.

```
<p-column field="newValue" header="User new value" >
    <template let-col let-list="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        // dropdown here
      </template>
</p-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. '#dropdownId' is dynamic. I am using angular2.

```
let td = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('#dropdownId').parentNode.parentNode;
this.renderer.setElementStyle(td, 'background-color', 'blue');
```